# Decode Non-English text with barcode reader C#.NET

Tags: .net, barcode, spire

hello I have this simple example of generating a bar code and decoding it again using Spire.Barcode library

```
        BarcodeSettings bcsettings = new BarcodeSettings();
        bcsettings.Data = "مرحباً";
        bcsettings.Type = BarCodeType.DataMatrix;
        BarCodeGenerator bcgen = new BarCodeGenerator(bcsettings);
        System.Drawing.Image bcimg = bcgen.GenerateImage();
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bcbitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bcimg);
        String bcdata = BarcodeScanner.ScanOne(bcbitmap);
        output.Text += bcdata;
```

the example works very well with English but the output shows like this when I use Arabic.

[image: Barcode output for Arabic]

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your `BarcodeScanner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code to your project:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BarcodeSettings bcsettings = new BarcodeSettings();

            bcsettings.Data = GetEncodingText("مرحباً");
            bcsettings.Data2D =GetEncodingText( "مرحباً");

            bcsettings.Type = BarCodeType.DataMatrix; 
            BarCodeGenerator bcgen = new BarCodeGenerator(bcsettings);
            System.Drawing.Image bcimg = bcgen.GenerateImage();
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bcbitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bcimg);
            String bcdata = BarcodeScanner.ScanOne(bcbitmap);
            output.Text += GetDecodingText(bcdata);

        }
        public string GetEncodingText(string unicodeStr)
        {
            string encodingResult = "";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unicodeStr);
            foreach (byte b in byteArray)
                encodingResult += (char)b;
            return encodingResult;
        }
        public string GetDecodingText(string unicodeStr)
        {
            string decodingResult = "";
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
            foreach (char c in unicodeStr)
                bytes.Add((byte)c);
            decodingResult = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
            return decodingResult;
        }
```